# Access denied phpmyadmin when connecting to www on synology nas

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, synology

I have a question which is indeed asked frequently.. but all the answers that were marked solved did nothing any good. thats why i have a question.

since yesterday i want to connect via PHP to a phpmyadmin database. I have no problems when the php project is inside the web folder. but since this project is outside currently it's not working.

this is what i use to make a connection to  the phpmyadmin database.

```
return [
    'dbname' => 'dbname',
    'host' => 'link_of_synology_nas.synology.me',
    'user' => 'the_user',
    'password' => 'the  password',
    'port' => 3306
];
```

i always get a error that is called:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'
```

[image]

i have dove into the phpmyadmin config and edit there some entries.. but even the internet did not  help. im not really into heavy networking. so if there is anyone who could help me for fixing this issue. would be appriciated.

Kind regards,

Beau den Heijer

Comment: Try `'host' => '127.0.0.1',` if phpMyAdmin is hosted on the same NAS.

Comment: @Code4R7, phpmyadmin needs to be accessible outside the network for others. so i can't use localhost :)

Comment: i need the public www address of my nas what synology provides. but the [1045] error  keeps showing no mather what i edit / add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Synology, install phpMyAdmin through Package Center and log in to phpMyAdmin. From there, go to "Gebruikersaccounts" and create a new account for external usage. Make sure you set "Servernaam" to "Elke host" and "Authenticatie Plugin" to "MySQL authenticatie". Also grant access to the database schema.

Now you should be able to use the newly created account to connect from external SQL clients.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing like the "client" is localhost but i think this connection is executed by the client or somewhere else

Comment: so php is executed outside the NAS where PHPmyadmin runs and also runs outside the network. i've made a user with all priviliges and lots of host entries.. but no results